# Elegant way to combine [[(Int, String)]] into [(Int, String)]?

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9

I am using Swift 4, Xcode 9.

Specifically, I have an array of arrays [[(Int, String)]] where Int is a rank and String is a Name + Items... that are combined using .joined(separator: ";").

The data might look like this:

```
[[1,"My Name;Item1;Item2"], [(5,"My Name;Item2;Item3"), (3,"My Second Name;Item1")]]
```

I want to combine the inner arrays so that:

1. Int adds for matching items based on the name (up to ";")
2. Strings add subsequent items if not already present

Combining my above example should lead to this:

```
[(6,"My Name;Item1;Item2;Item3"), (3,"My Second Name;Item1")]
```

I.e. input is `[[(Int, String)]]` and output is `[(Int, String)]`

Currently, I can achieve this through a fairly complex set of loops. With a large dataset, this results in a noticeable performance drop. Is there an elegant/simple way to combine these arrays as I am requesting?

Thank you for any guidance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Generally I would make this a comment because it doesn't answer the question, but it feels worth the trouble to explain exactly how you should change this.)

This is certainly possible, but don't. The answer is to replace this with an array of structs. Based on your data description:

```
struct Element {
    let rank: Int
    let name: String
    let items: Set<String> // Since you seem to want them to be unique and unordered
}

let elements: [[Element]] =
    [[Element(rank: 1, name: "My Name", items: ["Item1", "Item2"])],
     [Element(rank: 5, name: "My Name", items: ["Item2", "Item3"]),
      Element(rank: 3, name: "My Second Name", items: ["Item1"])]]

// You want to manage these by name, so let's make key/value pairs of all the elements
// as (Name, Element)
let namedElements = elements.joined().map { ($0.name, $0) }

// Now combine them as you describe. Add the ranks, and merge the items
let uniqueElements =
    Dictionary<String, Element>(namedElements,
                                uniquingKeysWith: { (lhs, rhs) -> Element in
                                    return Element(rank: lhs.rank + rhs.rank,
                                                   name: lhs.name,
                                                   items: lhs.items.union(rhs.items))
    })

// The result is the values of the dictionary
let result = uniqueElements.values

// Element(rank: 6, name: "My Name", items: Set(["Item3", "Item2", "Item1"]))
// Element(rank: 3, name: "My Second Name", items: Set(["Item1"]))
```

Comment: This is fantastic and appears to go above and beyond to redirect my logic. I’ll mark as correct once I test.

Comment: Works beautifully. The one thing I had to change was the return Element rank. For some reason it gave me the error that lhs.rank + rhs.rank was ambiguous without more context. I fixed this by adding let sum = lhs.rank + rhs.rank just above the return and then using sum as the value for rank. Thank you!